# Magento - Adding Initialisation Script to Page.xml

Tags: javascript, php, xml, magento

I apologise if this has been asked a million times, but I can’t find an answer anywhere, so perhaps it hasn’t!

I’ve added some .js files to page.xml, but also need to add the initialisation script for several plugins as well as some PHP.

How is this done exactly?

By initialisation script I mean the below;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#masonry');
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.feed-box',
    });  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: cant you add the above code in a js file and include that file in your   header ?

Comment: Doesn't work like that I'm afraid. It needs to be in the header. There are already some <script></script> in the header, not sure where they have come from though! None of the "Action" methods seem to do the right thing.

Comment: OK,looks like this can be done by adding the code to the page template...

"app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/THE_TEMPLATE.phtml"

...although the code does not initialise the plugin!

Comment: You just need to include that JS and the plugin will be initialized on document.ready()

Comment: Yeah, I have this working. Issues with JQuery conflicting with prototype.js now, there are a few documented fixes for this though.